# Bootstrapper will not skip if already installed

Tags: c#, deployment, installation

We use SAP Crystal Reports in our application. We have two versions of our application, for 32-bit and for 64-bit. With the 32-bit version, it works as expected: When we install the program and SAP Crystal Reports 32-bit is already installed on the target machine, SAP Crystal Reports is not installed again. However, this fails for the 64-bit version although we included a bypass property:

```
<BypassIf Property="CRRuntime64Version" Compare="VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo"  Value="13.0.13"/>
```

For some reason this does not work as expected. What should we do?

Comment: I have the exact same problem. The only workaround I have found is Under Commands section of the product.xml, find the command element and change the Arguments attribute to '/quiet /passive UPGRADE=1'. Source https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/830194/ClickOnce-Crystal-Reports-Redistributable-Upgrade

Comment: Thanks! But we currently use '/qf' and we would like that the setup program shows the user interface. '/quiet /passive' would disable the user interface. Is there any other way? Would '/qf UPGRADE=1' do the job?